# Xamarin DatePicker format issue

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

On one device I got the date format as `dd-mm-yyyy` while on the other I got `mm/dd/yyyy`.
But I have declared the format as `dd-mm-yyyy`. Then why I am getting different format in other device? I want the same format in every device.

How can I get the same date format in different devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was:

1. Creating `CultureInfo`

   `CultureInfo _cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");`
2. Do `ToString()` with required format.

   `string _dtNowString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt", _cultureInfo);`

This gives same date format in every device.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should set the CultureInfo first. This is a class provided by .NET and it carries about how the date and number should be displayed referring to info in object from that class. For more info check out the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netcore-3.1